# $routeProvider in angularjs not working properly

Tags: angularjs

```js
this is my test.js file
angular.module("testApp",['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when("/test",{
        templateUrl: 'test.html',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
    })
   .otherwise({
        redirectTo : "/test" 
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    
}]).controller("testCtrl",function(){
    this.message = "hello";
    console.log("in controller");
})
```

```html
this is index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>

 <script src="angular.js"></script>
 <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="test.js"></script>
 <base href="/">

</head>

<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>


this is test.html file

<div ng-controller="testCtrl as tCtrl">
  <h1>{{tCtrl.message}}</h1>
</div>
```

when I hit http://127.0.0.1:8080/ it is redirected http://127.0.0.1:8080/test and it is working fine with load all resources i.e controller and angualar.js.
but when i hit http://127.0.0.1:8080/test it doesn't load anything giving {{tCtrl.message}}

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: When you enter an url, the server side routing will run firstly. It looks for `/test` and don't see any handler, so nothing will be run (404 error). Try setting fallback url at server-side (or your dev server) to `index.html`.

Comment: When you see  {{tCtrl.message}} in browser there must be some errors in console, can you please post them?